# jQuery object memory size

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-management

I want to optimise the memory usage of my application.

Suppose I have a HTML file with a very large list element in it which 1000 list items.

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  ...
  <li>item 1000</li>
</ul>
```

If i create a jQuery object of the complete list, how would jQuery store the child nodes? Would it contain objects for each list item?

```
var list = $("ul");
```

Comment: I think it will be creating objects for every li items . DOM structure/heirarchy makes us to undertsand this better . Because of creating objects only we are able to find the elements in DOM.

Comment: If you're asking if the child DOM elements will be stored in the jQuery object itself, the answer is *no*. Only the `<ul>` elements will stored in that object, the children will be walked and wrapped on-demand e.g. when applying `children()` or `find()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would contain objects for each of the children, in the `ul` object propoerty `childNodes`.

Here is a quick demo I put together: http://jsfiddle.net/u9nLwwbf/

Comment: Note that `childNodes` is maintained by the DOM, not jQuery. That memory will always be spent, whether jQuery objects are created or not.